# Using declaration on variadic args. How to choose the correct function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I have a policy based design where I have some function `foo()` defined in some policies but not others. The base class always inherits from some class called `AlwaysBase` which has an inferior `foo()` function.

I want to make it so if a "better" `foo()` exists (one from a Policy class) that one will always be chosen.

Here is some code:

```
// logic for determining if a class has a member function (not really related)
template <class> struct sfinae_true: std::true_type{};
template <class T> static auto test_foo(int) -> sfinae_true<decltype(std::declval<T>().foo())>;
template <class> static auto test_foo(long) -> std::false_type;
template <class T> struct has_foo : decltype(test_foo<T>(0)){};

class AlwaysBase{ public: void foo(){ cout << "in AlwaysBase foo()" << endl; } };
class BPolicy{};
class CPolicy{ public: void foo(){ cout << "in Cpolicy foo()" << endl; } };

template<typename T, typename ...Args>
class A: public T, public A<Args...>
{
public:
    using std::conditional_t<has_foo<T>::value, T, AlwaysBase>::foo;
};

template<typename T>
class A<T>: public T, public AlwaysBase
{
public:
    using std::conditional_t<has_foo<T>::value, T, AlwaysBase>::foo;
};

int main()
{
    A<BPolicy> b;
    b.foo();     // outputs: In AlwaysBase foo()

    A<CPolicy> c;
    c.foo();     // outputs: In CPolicy foo()
    
    A<CPolicy, BPolicy> cb;
    cb.foo();    // outputs: In CPolicy foo()

    A<BPolicy, CPolicy> bc;
    bc.foo();    // outputs: In AlwaysBase foo() // I WANT THIS TO OUTPUT!!!!: In CPolicy foo
}
```

I understand what is happening here, when `BPolicy` is first, that using statement gets used in the variadic args class first and shadows any preceding using statement that would be found in the terminating base class (namely the CPolicy::foo).

I would like for the order to not matter when specifying policies, and if a Policy has a determinant, that one should always be chosen first over the `AlwaysBase::foo`.

Comment: Please remove the totally unneeded `inline` keyword... looks that you did not really know what it does :-)

Comment: What do you want to happen if multiple policies have a `foo`?

Comment: @Klaus copy and paste error from my somewhat rather complex function :)

Comment: @cigien then order would prevail, but it wouldn't really make sense in my application for those policies which contain a `foo` to be in there

Comment: I do not see why you are doing conditional approach in this case. Just have a base class an empty `foo()`, and override in derived class. No using declaration is necessary, as in classic CRTP pattern.

Comment: For me nothing of the code makes any sense! As the topmost class will provide a function foo() it will be taken, if not, a foo deeper in the hirarchy will be taken. As you AlwaysBase has a foo, that works without any SFINAE stuff!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use recursion. If empty lists are allowed, this is very easy:

```
// recursive invariant: As<Ts...>::foo is always the foo from the first capable Ts or from AlwaysBase
template<typename... Ts>
class A : public AlwaysBase { // template<> class A<>
public:
    // there are no capable Ts
    using AlwaysBase::foo;
};
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
class A<T, Ts...> : public T, public A<Ts...> {
public:
    // from the A<Ts...> superclass, not AlwaysBase
    // try to use T, fall back to Ts, and only then fall back to AlwaysBase
    using std::conditional_t<has_foo<T>::value, T, A<Ts...>>::foo;
};
```

Constraining to nonempty lists is a bit more annoying:

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
class A : public T, public A<Ts...> {
public:
    using std::conditional_t<has_foo<T>::value, T, A<Ts...>>::foo;
};
template<typename T>
class A<T> : public T, public AlwaysBase {
public:
    using std::conditional_t<has_foo<T>::value, T, AlwaysBase>::foo;
};
```

Order still matters, though. If two policies provide `foo`, the first one wins.

Comment: Can't catch your point. The code of OP already uses recursion, didn't he? BTW: your conditional makes no sense, as the compiler already pick the topmost foo() implementation.

Comment: @HTNW exactly what I was looking for and makes a lot of sense! thanks for the help!

Comment: @Klaus Yes, but also no. The `Ts` are incorporated as superclasses recursively, but the choice of `foo` is not. The OP's logic says "If the first of the `Ts` has `foo`, use it, otherwise `AlwaysBase::foo`", which is not recursive. I say "If the first of the `Ts` has `foo` use it, otherwise search recursively in the tail, using `AlwaysBase::foo` if that fails", which is. Also, removing the conditionals and allowing the compiler to choose for itself [causes ambiguity](https://godbolt.org/z/JQCGxD). Maybe I'm just overlooking something.

Comment: " and if a Policy has " says not "the first policy has. Maybe I read it wrong :-) My understanding of the question was: If one of the .... has use it, instead of default one. Anyway: If you only want to check for the first, you definitely do not need recursion, you simply pick the first or the default. And there is no ambiguity,as without the using clause, the topmost declaration will hide all others, even if there are ambiguous overloads.

Comment: @HTNW with the first approach you mention, is it possible to incorporate default template arguments?